# jquery: how to change the size of a div from center

Tags: jquery

When I use jQuery animate() function to change the size of a div, it always begins from left-top point. How can I make it zoom from center instead from corner.
For example, my code:

```
<div id="div1"></div>

<style>


#div1{
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
opacity: 0.4;
top: 40%;
left: 40%;
border-radius: 1000px;
margin: auto;
}
</style>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div1").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).animate(
    {width: 100, height: 100, opacity: 1},
    {duration: 500,
    easing: "easeOutBounce"}
    );
});
$("#div1").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate(
    {width: 50, height: 50, opacity: 0.4},
    {duration: 500,
    easing: "easeOutBounce"}
    );
});
});
</script>
```

This will change from left-top point but I want it staring from center.
Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest having parallel animation to move the top left corner. This would then appear to be growing from the centre. Sorry but I don't have the code to do this.

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show how the code is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Nalum/46pHK/) using @Schroedingers Cat's suggestion. I changed the top and left positions to pixel values rather than percentages.

JavaScript:

```
$("#div1").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        top: 75,
        left: 75,
        opacity: 1
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        easing: "easeOutBounce"
    });
});
$("#div1").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        top: 100,
        left: 100,
        opacity: 0.4
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        easing: "easeOutBounce"
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#div1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.4;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with percentages in your css, you can use the jQuery `position()` function to get the top and left starting coordinates, along with `width()` and `height()`, and use these as the base values for your animation.

You can also get the initial settings from the css which you can use in the `mouseOut` function.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yQtwy/)